# DataTable - Sorting the results according to a value in column

Tags: c#, sorting, datatable

Below is my DataTable values.

```
Cards   Signals
card1   DO
card1   DO
card2   DO
card2   DO
card2   DO
card3   DO
```

I want my DataTable which has the value `"card2"` at the top. How we can achieve this?

Comment: @RameshDurai did you check my answer

Comment: my answer is solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose `dtMy` is your current table, and you will get your sorted result in `dt`

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = new DataView(dtMy, "Cards= 'card2'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable();
        dt.Merge(new DataView(dtMy, "Cards<> 'card2'", "", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows).ToTable());
```